Can I serve a git repo and html from the same URI?
I have a small static website, generated by a script which I want to distribute along with the source data. Thus if I make a hook which runs git update-server-info, the HTML will be at https://example.com/whatever/ and the repo will be at https://example.com/whatever/.git/. All lovely.
However, the /.git part seems like cruft, since the server can tell whether it's being asked for a repo. So, three questions:

I'd like the HTML and the repo to be accessible via the same URI-- or at least, to put in a redirect. Is that reasonable practice?

This can perhaps be done by picking up git's initial request for info/refs, and redirecting it to .git/info/refs. Is that the best way?

I'm using nginx. If I wanted to do this for arbitrary similar sites in the future, without rewriting the config, I'd have expected to write something like rewrite (?<!/\.git)/info .git/info permanent. But when I test that, the lookbehind doesn't trigger, causing an infinite loop. What am I missing?


This is not the same question as 3261132, which is about not making the .git subdir available to the public.
